# PHP DateTime createFormat from invalid date

Tags: php, datetime

Hi I want to create DateTime object from date 1989-06-31. As you can see this date has bad count of days(June can't have 31 days). But calling this

```
$semi_valid_date = "1989-06-31";
$semi_valid_datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$semi_valid_date);
$valid_date = $semi_valid_datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

will store to `$valid_date` date 1989-07-01.

Is it possible to throw error, when month has more days, than it can have?

Comment: 6th month or aka June doesn't have 31 days. That's way first next day is selected after 06-30, which is 07-01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/checkdate) to validate the date before attempting to use it:

```
var_dump(checkdate(6, 31, 1989));
// bool(false)

var_dump(checkdate(6, 30, 1989));
// bool(true)
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pRfYxz)